# Azure MFA with OATH Tokens

Tags: authentication, azure, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I haven't found anything obvious that answers this question so I'm going to ask it here, if i find the answer I'm looking for I will share it with the community.

I am in the process of implementing Azure On-Premise Multi Factor Authentication.  All is going well.  The two way SMS works just dandy.  The Authenticator app works on my iPhone pretty good.  I've even managed to get our FortiGate devices to talk to it for Two Factor for our VPN connections.

I am now trying to figure out how to implement OATH tokens because my boss does not want to be dependent on the cellular network and because a large part of our mobile devices are BlackBerry's.

The thing that I have never fully understood is what do you enter when you log in?

SCENARIO 1: Lets say I just have an OATH token, no Authenticator app, and no PIN.  What do you enter in the username and password prompt?

SCENARIO 2:  What if I do have the Authenticator app on my phone but no cell signal.  Can I enter my username then the code generated in the app for my password?

Answer (score 0):

For Scenario 2: with no cell signal or the phone in airplane mode, using the phone app, put in your username and password. In a few moments you will be directed to anopther page and you will enter the 6 digit code on the app then you will get to your remote system

Answer (score 0):

You can use software or hardware tokens. Software token means that you install 2FA app on your device. Hardware tokens are devices intended special for generating OTPs. They are typically small and has a form of a key fob or a card (like [Protectimus Slim NFC](https://www.protectimus.com/slim-mini/)). These tokens provide an additional layer of protection. It means that you enter your username and password and then you will be asked to enter OTP generated by the token.

So, here are the answers:
Scenario 1: You should enter your username and your password and then you will be asked to enter OTP generated by your token.
Scenario 2: 2FA app does not need any internet connection. So even if you have no cell signal your app will generate OTPs.

Comment: Hi Christian, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)